# Collecting All The User Reviews From The AppAtore

Tags: ios, windows-store-apps, app-store

I'm doing a research on the app store reviews. My experiment needs a huge number of user reviews from the app store, and I need to collect it for 6 months. I have found a scraper that collects the user reviews from specific apps by entering their ids.
I wonder if it is possible to collect the reviews from all the applications in the app store without having to enter the app id?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can do that unless you have all applications ids.

Comment: Thank you! You're right. I'm thinking of using the RSS feed and many apps ID to collect as many reviews as possible. What do you think?

Comment: I think this is your only solution. Be aware that if you call to quickly the RSS feeds, some reviews will not be returned.